# How to check data is getting pushed into JSON or not

Tags: javascript, json, arrays

**JSON**

This is my JSON structure. I am pushing data into this on button click.

```
var arrtopic = {
    "info" : []
};
```

**JS**

I wrote this is function

```
arrtopic.info.push({ 
            "Name" :name,
            "Number" : num
        });
```

**JS for json data display**

```
function displayJson(){ 
    var obj = eval ("(" + arrtopic + ")");
    document.getElementById("newme").innerHTML=obj.info.Name;

}
```

This is not working, please suggest something

**Thank you in advance for your help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function displayJson(){ 

    document.getElementById("newme").innerHTML= arrtopic.info[0].Name;

}
```

Comment: Yes i am getting name on my <p id="newme">

Answer (score 1):

```
function displayJson(){ 
    var obj =JSON.parse(arrtopic);
    document.getElementById("newme").innerHTML=obj.info.Name;

}
```

You can also use `alert(obj.count);` to fine whether the items are being pushed into

Comment: I am getting this error in firebug.
**ReferenceError: Json is not defined**

Comment: @Phoenix It should be `JSON.parse`. Also depending on what browser you have to support you might have to use a shim

Comment: I am using firefox and chrome, what is shim??

Comment: JS is case sensitive use JSON all caps

Comment: However, I think JSON.Parse or JSON.Stringify is not needed

Answer (score 1):

You are doing correct just use

```
 console.log(arrtopic.info[0].Name);
```

instead of arrtopic.info.Name

Comment: Yes i am getting name on console